# Laravel Relation - Different Results with Static Vs Non-Static

Tags: laravel-5, static, relation, non-static

I've run in to a problem with Laravel which I cannot for the life of me work out.

I have the following models which are essentially:

```
class Team extends Model
{
    public function notices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Notice', 'notice_recipients');
    }
}

class Notice extends Model
{
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'notice_recipients');
    }
}
```

I have run into the problem where on my Team model:

```
dump($this->notices);
```

returns different results to:

```
dump(Team::find($this->id)->notices);
```

---

To investigate further I have the following code:

```
    dump($this->id); // = 20
    dump($this->notices()->toSql());
    dump($this->notices()->getBindings());
    dump($this->notices);
    dump(Team::find($this->id)->notices()->toSql());
    dump(Team::find($this->id)->notices()->getBindings());
    dump(Team::find($this->id)->notices);
```

Lines 2-3 output exactly the same as far as I can tell as lines 5-6 so I should be gettings the same results, however lines 4 and 7 output different results! (Line 4 seems to output only a selection of the results outputted by line 7).

The issue seems to happen only on certain Team models and it seems completely random as to whether the issue occurs or not on any particular model.

Any ideas as to what might be going on or how I might further debug this issue?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

notice_recipients table if has the following fields

id 
team_id 
notice_id

try this maybe this will work

```
    public function notices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Notice', 'notice_recipients', 'team_id', notice_id);
    }

public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team', 'notice_recipients', 'notice_id', 'team_id');
    }
```